# File permission problem

Tags: permissions, magento

I am running magento in dedicated server.CMS running with `root:root` as user and group.If magento downloads any extensions it is saving with `www-data:www-data` ownership.I want to know how can i set root:root for downloading files

or

How to set all files with `www-data:www-data` and make the files executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CMS running with root:root as user and group

**Don't** do that.

> How to set all files with www-data:www-data and make the files
>   executable?

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/magento
```

and make the Apache running as `www-data` user.

Comment: I m getting chmod: invalid mode: `www-data:www-data' message.Is it chmod or chown?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `chown`.

Comment: Thanks.How to make apache run as www-data user?

Comment: Open the Apache configuration file - `httpd.conf`, and change `User`, `Group` to www-data. Don't forget to restart.